# Classes in detail: Errors while designing a set of classes that work together

Tags: c++, class

I am having to create a program and design a set of classes that work together to simulate a car’s fuel gauge and odometer. These are the requirements:

The **FuelGauge** Class: This class will simulate a fuel gauge. Its responsibilities are:
•To know the car’s current amount of fuel, in gallons.
•To report the car’s current amount of fuel, in gallons.
•To be able to increment the amount of fuel by 1 gallon. This simulates putting fuel in the car. (The car can hold a maximum of 15 gallons.)
•To be able to decrement the amount of fuel by 1 gallon, if the amount of fuel is greater than 0 gallons. This simulates burning fuel as the car runs.

•The **Odometer** Class: This class should simulate the car’s odometer. Its responsibilities are:
•To know the car’s current mileage.
•To report the car’s current mileage.
•To be able to increment the current mileage by 1 mile. The maximum mileage the odometer can store is 999,999 miles. When this amount is exceeded, the odometer resets the current mileage to 0.
•To be able to work with a FuelGauge object. It should decrease the FuelGauge object’s current amount of fuel by 1 gallon for every 24 miles traveled. (The car’s fuel economy is 24 miles per gallon.)

Demonstrate the classes by creating instances of each. Simulate filling the car up with fuel, and then run a loop that increments the odometer until the car runs out of fuel. During each loop iteration, print the car’s current mileage and amount of fuel.

I am not to sure on how to work with class files and the main.cpp 
This is what I have and I keep getting errors and I'm not sure what to do. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Errors:

```
In file included from main.cpp:17:
FuelGauge.h:13: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of âfuelGaugeâ with no type
FuelGauge.h:18: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of âfuelGaugeâ with no type
FuelGauge.h: In member function âvoid FuelGauge::incrementFuelTank()â:
FuelGauge.h:30: error: expected â;â before â}â token
In file included from main.cpp:18:
Odometer.h: At global scope:
Odometer.h:15: error: âfâ was not declared in this scope
Odometer.h:15: error: invalid use of incomplete type âclass Odometerâ
Odometer.h:9: error: forward declaration of âclass Odometerâ
Odometer.h:15: error: expected primary-expression before â(â token
Odometer.h:15: error: expected primary-expression before âintâ
Odometer.h:15: error: expected primary-expression before â*â token
Odometer.h:15: error: âfâ was not declared in this scope
Odometer.h:15: error: a function call cannot appear in a constant-expression
Odometer.h:15: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of âPublicâ with no type
Odometer.h:16: error: expected â;â before â{â token
Odometer.h:21: error: expected â;â before âintâ
main.cpp: In function âint main()â:
main.cpp:25: error: no matching function for call to âOdometer::Odometer(int, FuelGauge*)â
Odometer.h:9: note: candidates are: Odometer::Odometer()
Odometer.h:9: note:                 Odometer::Odometer(const Odometer&)
Odometer.h:26: error: âvoid Odometer::incrementCurrentMileage()â is private
main.cpp:32: error: within this context
Odometer.h:21: error: âint Odometer::getCurrentAmtMiles()â is private
main.cpp:33: error: within this context
```

---

```
//main.cpp
#include <iostream> 
#include "FuelGauge.h"
#include "Odometer.h"

using namespace std;

int main ()
{
    FuelGauge fuel;
    Odometer odm(0, &fuel);

    for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
    {
        fuel.incrementFuelTank();
    }
    while (fuel.getCurrentAmtFuel() > 0)
    {
        odm.incrementCurrentMileage();
        cout << "Mileage: " << odm.getCurrentAmtMiles() << endl;
        cout << "Fuel Level: " << fuel.getCurrentAmtFuel() << " gallons" << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}

//FuelGauge.h
using namespace std;

#ifndef FUELGAUGE_H
#define FUELGAUGE_H

class FuelGauge
{
    private:
        int currentAmtFuel;

    public:
        fuelGauge (int gallons)
        {
            currentAmtFuel = gallons;
        }

        fuelGauge() {}

        int getCurrentAmtFuel () const
        {
            return currentAmtFuel;
        }

        void incrementFuelTank()
        {
            if (currentAmtFuel < 15)
            {
                currentAmtFuel++
            }
        }

        void decrementFuelTank()
        {
            if (currentAmtFuel > 0)
            {
                currentAmtFuel--;
            }
        }
};

#endif

//Odometer.h
#include "FuelGauge.h"

using namespace std;

#ifndef ODOMETER_H
#define ODOMETER_H
class Odometer
{
    private:
        int currentAmtMiles;
        FuelGauge *fuelG;

    Public:
        Odometer(int miles, FuelGauge *f)
        {
            currentAmtMiles = miles;
            fuelG = f;
        }

        int getCurrentAmtMiles ()
        {
            return currentAmtMiles;
        }

        void incrementCurrentMileage()
        {
            if(currentAmtMiles < 999999)
            {
                currentAmtMiles++;
            }
            if (currentAmtMiles == 999999)
            {
                currentAmtMiles = 0;
            }
        }

        void decrementCurrentMileage()
        {
            if (currentAmtMiles > 24)
            {
                currentAmtMiles--;
            }
        }
};

#endif
```

Comment: looks like your constructor is named fuelGauge, but your class is named FuelGauge

Comment: Your questions all have the same style, and you don't seem to be learning anything from our answers. When you write code, don't just pound it out until your wrists hurt and then try to fix the bugs (or ask others to fix them for you). Start with something small and simple that works perfectly, then add complexity a little at a time, testing at every step. If you get stuck, reduce your problem to a [minimal complete example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and stare at it for a while before you ask for help.

Answer (score 1):

Ideally, this should be designed as follows :-

1. Create a class called "car".
2. Two member variables of "car" should be objects of classes "FuelGauge" and "Odometer" respectively.
3. There should be a public member function "travel". This function should increment the mileage in Odometer by 1, and it should also increment a member variable "distance" of "car".
4. At every call of the function "travel", you should compute the change in the values of "distance". Once this difference reaches 25, you should set the fuel value to "Zero".

### **Advantages**

1. FuelGauge and Odometer objects reside inside a class "car". Thus the two objects are tied together inside the instance of "car". This simulates them as components of the same "car" object.
2. You keep a member variable "distance" in the "car" class. Thus you are capable of keeping a track of how much distance the car has travelled, and based on the change in its value, you can also figure out how many times did you have to fill up the tank and how many times did you have to shoot the Odometer limits. These are additional functionalities but they make a lot of sense from the perspective of a practical object such as "car".

You have to write the Code yourself.

1. The code you have pasted shows that you are not paying attention to basic programming rules. Check the spelling mistakes. FuelGauge is a class, but your constructor is fuelgauge. It should be FuelGauge.
2. You are using too many conditions. You do not need to check separately for < 999,999 and == 999,999. Just check for > and you are done.
3. From a design pattern perspective, your design of OdoMeter is wrong. It is not the job of odometer to reset itself based on fuel amount. It should be a higher system that monitors both. That allows for separability of classes which makes designing and understanding much simpler.
4. Many other optimizations are possible here and there, but do not matter, as your whole design should be rehauled.